# Java New Instance Falsy Claiming Empty Constructor

Tags: java, constructor, instance

I've been having this problem and I can't seem to find a solution, or even what I did to cause this problem. Here is the code where I'm having the issue:

```
  Button b1 = new Button(450, 200, "default_button", 500, 60, "BONES", 60) {public void leftClick (){
setCurrentHandler(handlerBone);
}}; //This code shows no errors


b1 = new Button(450, 200, "default_button", 500, 60, "BONES", 60) {public void leftClick() {
setCurrentHandler(handlerBone);
}}; //This code shows the error

handlerMuscle.addClickObject(new Button(10, 10, "button_x", 60, 60) {public void leftClick() {
setCurrentHandler(handlerMenu);
}}); //This is the code I want to use but shows an error
```

You can see the source of my problem. The first statement gives no errors, yet the second one does, and the third one was the original code I had, which worked at one point and for (seemingly) no reason has stopped working.

When hovering over the red underline, the pop-up box reads "The constructor Button() is undefined", and it suggests adding values to match the constructor. When this button is clicked, it adds redundant parameters, such as

```
b1 = new Button(t, t, name, t, t450, 200, "default_button", 500, 60, "BONES", 60) //etc.
```

This same code worked before and I've tried similar code in another program just to make sure I wasn't crazy, and it worked fine. Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: please add your code to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Note: you are missing a quotation mark `"` after BONES in your second bit of code.

Comment: Fixed, just a typo when I was copying my code from the screenshot. I couldn't copy the code directly because I deleted it. Thank you!

Comment: You still have an unmatched quote problem.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to answer my own question, I feel like an idiot. Hopefully someone will benefit from this post. Basically the problem has nothing to do with the constructor.

Essentially the problem with my code is that you can't end the block of code I had with }});  but rather you must separate this into two lines,

`}}
);`

I'm not really sure why this formatting issue causes a problem in Java (Because it seems as though this change in formatting shouldn't change the compiler's interpretation of the code), so if anyone has an answer to *that* question, let me know.

Comment: Sorry, this cannot be the answer, a newline in that position cannot change the semantics of the program;

Comment: I agree that this shouldn't be the answer, but it did work for me for some reason.

Comment: You changed something else in the process.